# fullcalendar: stop current date from being selected

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using primeng fullcalendar's wrapper component for creating a scheduler which is using the agendaweek view for showing the week appointments. Does anyone knows how to stop the scheduler from applying the colors shown on the image for the current date (shown in the image)? Is there a property? or it is controlled through CSS?

[image]

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control it via css:

```
.fc-today{
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbtjsa62/)